# Expo's BarCodeScanner crashes when sacaning using the build

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo, barcode-scanner

App crashes when scanning a barcode using Expo's `BarCodeScanner`

I am very new to programming and expo, so I apologize in advance for the lack of precision.
I made an application using Expo 34.0.1 where I use [expo’s expo-barcode-scanner](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner/). The app works perfectly on `expo start`; however, when I run `expo build:android` the scanning fails. The camera opens but as soon as a code is scanned, the app restarts.

(I didn’t test it on IOS)

```
"expo": "^34.0.1",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",
"sdkVersion": "33.0.0",
```

```
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
```

```
<BarCodeScanner
        onBarCodeScanned={this.handleBarCodeScanned}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
>
</BarCodeScanner>
```

I expect it to work as in development but instead the app restarts as soon as a code is scanned

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is from how your permission is set. You need to check where your permission is being called from. I have mine being called from componentWillMount()

Comment: It worked !
I could never have guessed that this was the issue and to be honest, I initially thought that this solution wouldn't work because the app actually opens the camera and it worked on development.
Thanks a lot! 
(Btw, my permission was being called from componentDidMount())